# Oracle SQL performance tests with Turn off cache

Tags: sql, database, oracle, database-performance

I would like to test performance of query, but the problem is that database is using cached memory, so the result are not reliable.

How can i turn off caching/clear cache memory(and do not impact other users significant) ?

I am using Oracle 11.2 database.

Answer (score 3):

**DON'T** do this on your production server, but

You can do the following :

```
alter system flush shared_pool 
alter system flush buffer_cache
```

This will flush the library cache and the buffer pool.

Note: this isn't going to give you 'real world' situations as there will normally be some data in memory when running on a production server but it will show you what its like with a 'fresh' database

Comment: Hmm... did you ever use these commands while thousand of users works? :)

Comment: I would never condone this in a production environment, that would be rather daft, I'll edit ha

Comment: It shoudn't be 'Don't do this on your production instance' ? Cache is per server or per instance?

Comment: Its per instance, but that leads me to ask; do you have another instance of Oracle running on the same server that your main instance is running?

Comment: Well i was working on system that on production server was only production instance but on other server we had few instance(who cares about non prod ? :-) )

Comment: Why do you care about flushing the shared pool? I understand flushing the buffer cache; I don't think it makes any sense for anyone to test the performance of parsing a query, so why flush the shared pool?

Answer (score 1):

Caching isn't a problem, it's a feauture. If you wish to get useful results, you should test the query using real database state, with caching among others. If you test 'without caching', you'll get a value which will never happened in production (except maybe very rare case immediately after database restart).

Comment: So when i'm changing hints and result of query are cached, the result time should be different(if new hints are better/worse) ? Are hints working on cache ? Or only when i'm extracting data from disc? 
One more question cache - for single query the cache is deleted when is outdated and when one of query's object was modified(insert/update/delete)? What are condition for deleting from cache?

Comment: Query result does not cached at all, it's senseless. Generally you ask questions which means I should answer you significant part of [Oracle Database Concepts](https://docs.oracle.com/cloud/latest/db112/CNCPT/toc.htm). Don't romance about caching, model into your head is completely wrong. Just read about buffer cache, how Oracle maintain read consistency and so on.

Comment: Utter nonsense. What is being cached is data, not the result of the query... but in many cases accessing the data (and, specifically, accessing it in the most efficient way) is what performance is all about. In a normal operation a query is run perhaps once a day, but when you performance-test you may want to run it ten times in a row. It makes perfect sense to NOT want caching (of data read from disk to memory) to show much faster execution than you might get "in real life" (when there is no reason for the data to be in memory already).

Comment: You think that when you executes a query, it's data will flood the cache and will used when you executes this query another time; it's generally wrong. If it will be so, caching for production environment would almost fail because every query would dramatically spoil cache for others. In sober fact when query needs to scan a large table, it uses the far end of the LRU (least recently used) list so only several blocks would be cached after scan. It depends of CACHE|NOCACHE table creating clause, of keeping into buffer cache ability and many other things, but generally cache is more clever than